# How to get a data from a input box in html and pass it as a parameter in Rest API request in Flask Python

Tags: python, html, http, flask, jinja2

I need to create an API end point like :

```
@app.route('/user/<username>')
def user(username)
  -- do something with the username
```

in the index.html the code for input box is :

```
<input type="username" name="user_name" id="uname" placeholder="Input your  name">
```

Pls advise how I can pass this input as the 'username' variable?

Comment: You want to query `/user/<username>` api after user entered that `username` ?

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed  solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value after user submit. Using javascript to get that value and make the request to Flask server.

```
function makeRequest(event) {
  fetch('/user/'+ event.target.value)
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response)
    })
}
....
<input type="text" id="foo" value="bar" onkeyup="makeRequest(this)" />
```